# How to improve recursive function in C?

Tags: c, function, recursion, iteration

i have a program with various recursive functions.
I now need to optimize the code to run the program faster: i checked with profiler and, a part from the biggest function with lots of checks, i have two functions that require a lot of time every run.
One (Unmarked_Nodes) is like this:

```
typedef struct node* tree;

struct node{
char* data;
tree left;
tree right;
int marker;
};

static int remaining = 0;

int main(){
...
}

int Unmarked_Nodes(tree root) {
  if (root != NULL) {
    Unmarked_Nodes(root->left);
    if (root->marker == 0)
      remaining++;
    Unmarked_Nodes(root->right);
  }
return remaining;
}
```

The other is similar but instead of the if cycle it has a printf of data.
The other, however, is faster than this... why? Or instead: how can i improve the code to make it run faster?
Thanks in advance

Comment: On an unrelated note, but when you call `Unmarked_Nodes` recursively, what happens with the values that it returns?

Comment: The correct answer to your question is to get rid of the recursion. For example you can trivially implement this as a loop instead. One way to do so is to provide a `tree* parent [DEPTH];` array. Each time you go left or right, save the parent and keep track of your current tree depth.

Comment: @Lundin i did not really understand your hint about depth, how would it help me? Sorry

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i just need that value to be printed and to do some checks in some if conditions into the main program

Comment: @patosette The only thing that recursion is doing for you in C is essentially to store a local copy of all local variables/parameters per recursive call, so that once you return from one call to another, you resume where you were previously. When iterating through a tree, you don't need this functionality if each node has a parent pointer. However, storing a parent pointer in every node uses up a bit of extra memory, hence a separate array to keep track of where you are can be used instead.

Comment: Why are you calling `Unmarked_Nodes` to count the remaining unmarked nodes each time instead of maintaining the count (anytime a node is marked or unmarked, decrement or increment the count of remaining unmarked nodes)?

Comment: Does `Unmarked_Nodes` really need to use an external counter? It could sum the value of the two recursive calls and the value for the root, e.g. `int Unmarked_Nodes(tree root) {` `int remaining = 0;` `if (root != NULL) {` `remaining += Unmarked_Nodes(root->left);` `if (root->marker == 0)` `remaining++`; `remaining += Unmarked_Nodes(root->right);` `}` `return remaining;` `}`.

Comment: @Lundin And if a reasonable limit on `DEPTH` cannot be assumed, it could be changed to `tree **parent` pointing to a reallocatable dynamic memory block.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes and one can keep track of how much that's allocated and realloc a generous amount (twice the size or such) each time. But dynamic allocation is also slow, so it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Lundin A hybrid approach could be used. Start with `parent` pointing to a preallocated array, and if it is not long enough, allocate a dynamic block and `memcpy` the current stack of parent pointers to it.

Comment: Passing `remaining` as a parameter would allow the right recursion to be a tail call.

Comment: Re "*The other, however, is faster than this... why?*", There's no way that's true if that's the only difference.

Comment: What @ikegami said.  Please list the "other".

Answer (score 1):

Candidate improvements: might help a little although answer remains O(n).

**Recurse less often**

Loop inside the function for one of the children.

**Avoid global**

Simply not needed.

**Use `const`**

No so much a speed improvement, yet allows for use with constant data.

**Avoid hiding pointers**

---

```
int Unmarked_Nodes(const struct node *root) {
  int remaining = 0;
  while (root != NULL) {
    remaining += Unmarked_Nodes(root->left);
    if (root->marker == 0) {
      remaining++; 
    }
    root = root->right;
  } 
  return remaining;
}
```

---

Perhaps only recurse when both children are non-`NULL`.  Test null-ness at the end of the loop since it is initially false for all recursive entry.

```
static int Unmarked_Nodes2r(const struct node *root) {
  int remaining = 0;
  do {
    if (root->marker == 0) {
      remaining++; 
    }
    if (root->left) {
      if (root->right) {
        remaining += Unmarked_Nodesr(root->right);
      }
      root = root->left;
      // continue;  // Could skip loop test.
    } else {
      root = root->right;
    }
  } while (root);
  return remaining;
}

int Unmarked_Nodes2(const struct node *root) {
  return root ? Unmarked_Nodes2r(root) : 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems a bit faster, thanks

Comment: @patosette Added another to help reduce recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of more information, it would seem that you likely "visit" the tree three times: once for 'marking' nodes (for whatever purpose), once to 'print' marked (or unmarked) nodes, and once more to reset those marks.

Presuming that 'marked nodes' are the interesting ones, consider using a dynamic array of pointers (malloc/realloc in suitable increments) to build a list of only those nodes, print from that list (no 2nd tree traversal), then `free()` the list (no 3rd tree traversal).

You wouldn't need to 'mark/unmark' anything. Interesting nodes added to the suggested list mean that those nodes are 'marked', and 'unmarked' when the list is erased.

You may need to consider if 'marking' may encounter unwanted duplicates.

Another suggestion is to consider transforming the tree into a list once it is filled. Then, use conventional binary search of that list to mark 'nodes', and a sweep through to erase marks (presuming the same list is to be reused multiple times.

Another suggestion relates to whether you are marking to `include` or to `exclude` from the print traversal. If marked nodes are `included`, then simply 'unmark' them as you print them. If marked nodes are `excluded`, then mark all those other unmarked nodes being printed that haven't previously been 'excluded' and remember whether '0' means 'marked' or if '1' means marked for the next time it comes to searching/marking.